# Как настроить отображение вызова url метода get?

Tags: python, aiohttp

Необходимо, чтобы данные передавались в скрипт по такому адресу:
`http://localhost:11111/scan/192.168.1.1/10/100`, однако отображается он лишь по адресу `http://localhost:11111/scan?ip=192.168.1.1&begin_port=10&end_port=100`.
Как это можно исправить? вот код:

```py
from aiohttp import web
import jinja2
import aiohttp_jinja2


async def method(request):
    param1 = request.rel_url.query['ip']
    param2 = request.rel_url.query['begin_port']
    param3 = request.rel_url.query['end_port']
    result = "ip: {}, begin_port: {}, end_port: {}".format(param1, param2, param3)
    return web.Response(text=str(result))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_route('GET', "/scan", method)

    web.run_app(app,host='localhost', port=11111)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Сейчас вы используете GET-параметры в адресе.**

---

Для того чтобы путь был как в вашем вопросе вам нужно использовать либо [Named Resources](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#reverse-url-constructing-using-named-resources), если у вас статические пути, либо их комбинацию вместе с [Variable Resources](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#variable-resources), если пути формируются динамически.